# Java GitHub HTTPS/SSL request gives 404 response

Tags: java, ssl, https, github-api

I’m developing a small REST client for Java, and my using GitHub’s API while testing.
I can’t seem to figure out what i’v done wrong, here is the code that makes the https request.

Link to the repo: https://github.com/sigurdsvela/JREST

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)ourl.openConnection();

if (protocol == Protocol.HTTPS) { //protocol is Protocol.HTTPS
   SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
   ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
}

System.out.println("Sending " + method + " request to " + ourl + "?" + urlParameters);
connection.setRequestMethod(method.getName());
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.toString().getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

connection.setUseCaches (false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

//Send request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters.toString());
wr.flush();
wr.close();

System.out.println("Server responded with " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());

//Get Response  
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

When I run this code i get a FileNotFound from the last line, and the System.out.println("Server responded whi.... print that the server responded with 404 Not Found.

The System.out.println("Sending " + method.... print out the url its requesting. I’ve copy pasted it into my browser, and then it works fine. Am i making some false assumption? Is there something i have forgotten.

I'm sending a get.

I've also tried to remove the if (protocol == Protocol.HTTPS) condition and have it always be a HttpsURLConnection, instead of casting it. That didn't work either, and I was still  getting a 404 with the same message.

The URL I’m testing against, if relevant is:
api.github.com/repos/sigurdsvela/loveletters

Comment: Are you making a GET request or a POST request? It would be helpful to know the full URL, method, params, and everything else that goes into the request you're making to the API.

Comment: Also, the protocol should always be `https` because the entire API is served on that. Your conditional is wrong in that context. It should instead raise an exception if the protocol is not `https`.

Comment: @IvanZuzak I'm making a GET request.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I've tried to remove the condition and make it so that I'm always sending an https request as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Since you're making a GET request, the content-length, content-type and content-language headers are pointless and might be causing problems. Can you try removing those headers and retrying the request?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it with no success.